# Mongodb positional update all $[] doesn't seem to work

Tags: arrays, mongodb, operator-keyword

I have an event collection like so:

```
{title: "Some Title", description: "Some Description", products: [{_id: "owkaowakdowakd", quantity: 15}]}
```

And I want to add a field "reserved" with an empty array to all the elements of the products array. To get this result:

```
{title: "Some Title", description: "Some Description", products: [{_id: "owkaowakdowakd", quantity: 15, reserved: [] }]}
```

Looking at the documentation, you can make a change on all the elements of an array using the $[] operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#positional-update-all

```
db.events.updateMany( {"products.reserved": {$exists: false}}, {$set: {"products.$[].reserved": []}})
```

But this returns me an error:

```
2019-12-17T16:03:43.399+0000 E  QUERY    [js] WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 28,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'reserved' in element {0: null}",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "products.reserved" : {
                "$exists" : false
            }
        },
        "u" : {
            "$set" : {
                "products.$[].reserved" : [ ]
            }
        },
        "multi" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    }
}) :
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 28,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot create field 'reserved' in element {0: null}",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "products.reserved" : {
                "$exists" : false
            }
        },
        "u" : {
            "$set" : {
                "products.$[].reserved" : [ ]
            }
        },
        "multi" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    }
})
```

I also tried to modify the quantity of each element, because this already exists, but it returns the same error ! "Cannot create field 'quantity'..."

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using. The all positional operator `$[]` is only available `>=3.6`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpfull

[Add Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)